# How to render a view in Express by passing at the same time json object

Tags: json, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I have a problem and I'm looking for a solution to figure out it. In ExpressJS 4 I'm using Jade as template engine and AngularJS as client side framework.
I get through mongoose module a list of car brands in my mongodb. Everything works. The problem is if I call render along with json.stringify, the browser hungs and I don't get any page.
Which could be the best way to pass a json and at the same time render a jade file? The next move would be to create a service to the client side and get the json in order to pass it to the view

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next){

    Car.find()
        .sort({brand:1})
        .select('brand')
        .exec(function(err, brand){ 
            if(err) return next(err);
                //res.json(brand);
            res.render('index', 
                                 JSON.stringify(brand), 
                                 {pageTitle: 'Home'});
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the JSON to your template?

Comment: Actually I don't know if I should pass it to my template. What I know is I have to render the view since it is in jade format and pass the object brands (taken from my db) in the way that when I call $http.get in an angular controller I got the list in an angular/jade page

Answer (score 0):

I have just found three good and different solution to my own problem

http://www.mircozeiss.com/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-a-server-to-angular/